# Hive Permission denied with insert overwrite directory

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hive, hdfs

I got permission denied failure from hdfs while running the command below:

```
hive -e "insert overwrite directory '/user/hadoop/a/b/c/d/e/f' select * from table_name limit 10;"
```

The error message is:

```
Permission denied: user=hadoop, access=WRITE, inode="/user/hadoop/a/b":hdfs:hive:drwxrwxr-x
```

But when I run : `hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/a`, I get:

```
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-04-08 00:56 /user/hadoop/a/b
```

It seems I have opened full permission on the folder b, why did I still get permission denied?

PS: I have set `hive.insert.into.multilevel.dirs=true` in hive config file.

Comment: what about other nested directories? have you tried 'hadoop fs -chmod 777 -R /user/hadoop/a' ?

Comment: @arghtype Yes, I have tried this but it still doesn't work. I wonder why hive gets permission "drwxrwxr-x" while "hadoop fs -ls" gets permission "drwxrwxrwx" of the same folder?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have solved it simply by using the fully qualified HDFS path. Like this.

```
hive -e "insert overwrite directory 'hdfs://<cluster>/user/hadoop/a/b/c/d/e/f' select * from table_name limit 10;"
```

See [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/112754/insert-overwrite-directory-beeline.html) a mention of this issue.

However, I do not know the root cause but it's not related to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal then try this:

1.) Change user to root:

```
su
```

2.) Change user to hdfs:

```
su hdfs
```

3.) Then run this command:

```
hadoop fs -chown -R hadoop /user/hadoop/a
```

Now you can try the command you were running.

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: Just check using hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/, which user has the access whether it is hadoop/hive ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not actually with the directory permissions. Hive should have access to the path, what I mean by that is not on the files level.

Below are the steps on how you can grant access to the hdfs path and to the database to a user/group. Comments on each command starts with `#`

```
#Login as hive superuser to perform the below steps
create role <role_name_x>;

#For granting to database
grant all on database to role <role_name_x>;

#For granting to HDFS path
grant all on URI '/hdfs/path' to role <role_name_x>;

#Granting the role to the user you will use to run the hive job
grant role <role_name_x> to group <your_user_name>;

#After you perform the below steps you can validate with the below commands
#grant role should show the URI or database access when you run the grant role check on the role name as below

show grant role <role_name_x>;

#Now to validate if the user has access to the role

show role grant group <your_user_name>;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343036/impala-how-to-query-against-multiple-parquet-files-with-different-schemata/48343537#48343537) is one of my answer to the similar question through impala. [More on hive permissions](http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-authorization-models-and-hive-security/)

Other suggestion based on other answers and comments here, If you want to see the permissions on some hdfs path or file `hdfs dfs -ls` is not your friend to know more about the permissions and its old school approach. you can use `hdfs dfs -getfacl /hdfs/path` will give you the complete details, result looks something like below.

```
 hdfs dfs -getfacl /tmp/
# file: /tmp
# owner: hdfs
# group: supergroup
# flags: --t
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```