# DataFrame.write.parquet - Parquet-file cannot be read by HIVE or Impala

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, parquet

I wrote a DataFrame with pySpark into HDFS with this command:

```py
df.repartition(col("year"))\
.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 1000000)\
.parquet('/path/tablename', mode='overwrite', partitionBy=["year"], compression='snappy')
```

When taking a look into the HDFS I can see that the files are properly laying there. Anyhow, when I try to read the table with HIVE or Impala, the table cannot be found.

Whats going wrong here, am I missing something?

Interestingly, `df.write.format('parquet').saveAsTable("tablename")` works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an expected behaviour from spark as:

- **`df...etc.parquet("")`** writes the data to [HDFS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html) location and won't create any table in Hive.
- but **`df..saveAsTable("")`** creates the [table](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable) in hive and writes data to it.

> In the case the table already exists, behavior of this function
>   depends on the save mode, specified by the mode function (default to
>   throwing an exception). When mode is Overwrite, the schema of the
>   DataFrame does not need to be the same as that of the existing table.

That's the reason why you are **`not able to find table in hive`** after performing **`df...parquet("")`**